# Grid won't populate in free-jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I can't get the grid to populate my data. The correct number of rows shows up, but everything is empty (in my case, 8 empty rows). I am using jqGrid-free 4.15.5, jQueryUI 1.21.1, jQuery 3.5.1.

Is there something simple that I'm doing wrong?

Some things that are important to me:

- loadonce: true (so that I get my dataset one time and do client sorting from there)
- forceClientSorting: true

Also, I've seen varying solutions to pagers, so I'm not sure if I'm doing that correctly. From what I understand, simply setting pager: true should be sufficient with this version of jqGrid.

Controller Action:

```
public IActionResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
        {
            int pageIndex = page - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            List<SubCampaignData> subCampaignData = new List<SubCampaignData>();
            
                subCampaignData = database.SubCampaignData
                    .Include(scd => scd.ContentPriority)
                    .Include(scd => scd.DataSources)
                    .Include(scd => scd.DeliveryMethod)
                    .Include(scd => scd.DeliveryPriority)
                    .Include(scd => scd.Contacts)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.Role)
                    .ToList();

            var sortColumn = typeof(SubCampaignData).GetProperty(sidx);
            if (sord.ToUpper() == "ASC")
            {
                subCampaignData = subCampaignData.OrderBy(scd => sortColumn.GetValue(scd, null)).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                subCampaignData = subCampaignData.OrderByDescending(scd => sortColumn.GetValue(scd, null)).ToList();
            }
            
            var gridData = subCampaignData.Select(scd => new
            {
                Campaign = scd.Campaign,
                SubCampaign = scd.SubCampaign,
                BulkCampaignName = scd.BulkCampaignName,
                DeliveryMethodName = scd.DeliveryMethod.DeliveryMethodName,
                AutomationTriggerName = scd.AutomationTriggerName,
                MasterDataExtension = scd.MasterDataExtension,
                Purpose = scd.Purpose,
                Active = scd.Active.ToString(),
                FailureContactName = string.Join(';', scd.Contacts.Where(c => c.Role.RoleName.ToUpper() == "FAILURE CONTACT").Select(c => c.Name).ToList()),
                DeliveryPriorityName = scd.DeliveryPriority.PriorityName,
                ContentPriorityName = scd.ContentPriority.PriorityName,
                EscalateAfter = scd.EscalateAfter,
                ClientName = string.Join(';', scd.DataSources.Select(ds => ds.ClientName).ToList()),
                SourceJob = scd.SourceJob,
                MainframeFileName = scd.MainframeFileName,
                AggregationJob = scd.AggregationJob,
                AggregationRunTime = scd.AggregationRunTime,
                SendTime = scd.SendTime,
                RunFrequency = scd.RunFrequency,
                RunDays = scd.RunDays,
                RunMonths = scd.RunMonths,
                SendPend = scd.SendPend,
                SendPendDelay = scd.SendPendDelay,
                SendPendReason = scd.SendPendReason,
                RegressionScripts = scd.RegressionScripts.ToString(),
                ConfirmedActiveDate = FormatNullableDateTime(scd.ConfirmedActiveDate),
                StartDate = FormatNullableDateTime(scd.StartDate),
                Resend = scd.Resend,
                ResendAbility = scd.ResendAbility.ToString(),
                RecreateAbility = scd.RecreateAbility.ToString(),
                ResendRecreateDetails = scd.ResendRecreateDetails,
                BusinessOwnerName = string.Join(';', scd.Contacts.Where(c => c.Role.RoleName.ToUpper() == "BUSINESS OWNER").Select(c => c.Name).ToList()),
                BusinessSponsorName = string.Join(';', scd.Contacts.Where(c => c.Role.RoleName.ToUpper() == "BUSINESS SPONSOR").Select(c => c.Name).ToList()),
                BusinessSponsorEmailAddress = string.Join(';', scd.Contacts.Where(c => c.Role.RoleName.ToUpper() == "BUSINESS SPONSOR").Select(c => c.EmailAddress).ToList()),
                BusinessSponsorConfirmedDate = string.Join(';', FormatNullableDateTimes(scd.Contacts.Where(c => c.Role.RoleName.ToUpper() == "BUSINESS SPONSOR").Select(c => c.ConfirmedDate).ToList())),
                FailureContactEmailAddress = string.Join(';', scd.Contacts.Where(c => c.Role.RoleName.ToUpper() == "FAILURE CONTACT").Select(c => c.EmailAddress).ToList()),
                FailureContactConfirmedDate = string.Join(';', FormatNullableDateTimes(scd.Contacts.Where(c => c.Role.RoleName.ToUpper() == "FAILURE CONTACT").Select(c => c.ConfirmedDate).ToList())),
                SmeAnalystName = string.Join(';', scd.Contacts.Where(c => c.Role.RoleName.ToUpper() == "SME/ANALYST").Select(c => c.Name).ToList()),
                SmeAnalystEmailAddress = string.Join(';', scd.Contacts.Where(c => c.Role.RoleName.ToUpper() == "SME/ANALYST").Select(c => c.EmailAddress).ToList()),
                SmeAnalystConfirmedDate = string.Join(';', FormatNullableDateTimes(scd.Contacts.Where(c => c.Role.RoleName.ToUpper() == "SME/ANALYST").Select(c => c.ConfirmedDate).ToList())),
            }).ToArray();

            return Json(gridData);
        }
```

View (grid function):

```
 $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var mydata = [
            { id: "10", campaign: "Agent AutoReply Emails", subcampaign: "FAO_Agent_Inhouse_SoldQuote", commdeliverycampaign: "", deliverymethod: "Triggered Send", automationtriggeredsend: "Agent_AutoReply", masterdataextension: "Agent_AutoReply", purpose: "Sent to Agency when PGR has written new business for a customer on the Agency's behalf", active: "true", failurecontact: "", deliverypriority: "Medium", contentpriority: "Medium", escalateafter: "2", datasource: "Probill", sourcejob: "", mainframefile: "", inputfile: "", aggregationjob: "", aggregationruntime: "", sendtime: "Real-time", runfrequency: "Daily", rundays: "SMTWThFSa", runmonths: "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", sendpend: "N", sendpenddelay: "", sendpendreason: "", regression: "false", confirmactivedate: "2020-07-22", startdate: "", resend: "", resendability: "false", recreateability: "true", resendcomments: "Can recreate the list of Agencies from a report for the date.", businessowner: "", businesssponsor: "Dan Merk;Patrick D Astolfo", sponsoremail: "Dan_Merk@progressive.com;Patrick_DAstolfo@progressive.com", sponsorconfirmdate: "2020-01-30", failureemail: "", failureconfirmdate: "", smeanalyst: "", smeanalystemail: "", smeanalystconfirmed: "", metadata: "" }
        ],
            initDateEdit = function (elem, options) {
                // we need get the value before changing the type
                var orgValue = $(elem).val(), newformat,
                    cm = $(this).jqGrid("getColProp", options.name);

                $(elem).attr("type", "date");
                if ((Modernizr && !Modernizr.inputtypes.date) || $(elem).prop("type") !== "date") {
                    // if type="date" is not supported call jQuery UI datepicker
                    $(elem).css({ width: "8em" }).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                        autoSize: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        showWeek: false
                    });
                } else {
                    // convert date to ISO
                    if (orgValue !== "") {
                        newformat = cm.formatoptions != null && cm.formatoptions.newformat ?
                            cm.formatoptions.newformat :
                            $(this).jqGrid("getGridRes", "formatter.date.newformat");
                        $(elem).val($.jgrid.parseDate.call(this, newformat, orgValue, "yy-mm-dd"));
                    }
                    $(elem).css("width", "11em");
                }
            },
            initDateSearch = function (elem) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(elem).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                        autoSize: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        showWeek: false,
                        showButtonPanel: true
                    });
                }, 50);
            },
            numberTemplate = {
                formatter: "number", align: "right", sorttype: "number",
                editrules: { number: true, required: true },
                searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge", "nu", "nn", "in", "ni"] }
            };
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: "/Home/GridData",
            datatype: "json",
            //data: mydata,
            mtype: "GET",
            colModel: [
                { name: "act", template: "actions", frozen: true },
                { name: "Campaign", label: "Campaign Name", width: 120, editable: false, frozen: true },
                { name: "SubCampaign", label: "SubCampaign Name", width: 141, editable: true, frozen: true },
                {
                    name: "BulkCampaignName", label: "Bulk Campaign", width: 120,
                    editrules: { edithidden: true }, editable: true, hidden: true
                },
                {
                    name: "DeliveryMethodName", label: "Delivery Method", width: 120, formatter: "select",
                    formatoptions: { value: "Adhoc Bulk, Bulk, Bulk Text Messaging, Triggered Send, Triggered Text Messaging", defaultvalue: "Bulk" },
                    stype: "select",
                    searchoptions: { value: ":Any;Adhoc Bulk:Adhoc Bulk;Bulk:Bulk;Bulk Text Messaging:Bulk Text Messaging;Triggered Send:Triggered Send;Triggered Text Messaging:Triggered Text Messaging" },
                    editable: true
                },
                { name: "AutomationTriggerName", label: "Automation/Triggered Send", width: 185, editable: true },
                { name: "MasterDataExtension", label: "Master Data Extension", width: 155, editable: true },
                { name: "Purpose", label: "Purpose", width: 155, editable: true },
                {
                    name: "Active", label: "Active", width: 120, align: "center", formatter: "checkbox",
                    stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" },
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "Yes" }
                },
                { name: "FailureContactName", label: "Failure Contact", width: 155, editable: true },
                {
                    name: "DeliveryPriorityName", label: "Delivery Priority", width: 120, formatter: "select",
                    formatoptions: { value: "Low, Low-Medium, Medium, Medium-High, High", defaultvalue: "Medium" },
                    editable: true
                },
                {
                    name: "ContentPriorityName", label: "Content Priority", width: 120, formatter: "select",
                    formatoptions: { value: "Low, Low-Medium, Medium, Medium-High, High", defaultvalue: "Medium" },
                    editable: true
                },
                { name: "EscalateAfter", label: "Escalate After (days)", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "ClientName", label: "Data Source", width: 100, editable: true },
                { name: "SourceJob", label: "Source Job", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "MainframeFileName", label: "Mainframe File", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "AggregationJob", label: "AggregationJob", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "AggregationRunTime", label: "Aggregation Run Time", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "SendTime", label: "Send Time", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "RunFrequency", label: "Run Frequency", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "RunDays", label: "Run Days", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "RunMonths", label: "Run Months", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "SendPend", label: "SendPend", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "SendPendDelay", label: "SendPend Delay", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "SendPendReason", label: "SendPend Reason", width: 120, editable: true },
                {
                    name: "RegressionScripts", label: "Regression Scripts", width: 120, align: "center", formatter: "checkbox",
                    stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" },
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "true:false", defaultValue: "false" }
                },
                {
                    name: "ConfirmedActiveDate", label: "Last Confirmed Active", width: 120, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                    formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "Y-m-d" }, editable: true,
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch }
                },
                {
                    name: "StartDate", label: "Start Date", width: 120, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                    formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "Y-m-d" }, editable: true,
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch }
                },
                { name: "Resend", label: "Resend", width: 120, editable: true },
                {
                    name: "ResendAbility", label: "Business Can Resend", width: 120, align: "center", formatter: "checkbox",
                    stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" },
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "true:false", defaultValue: "false" }
                },
                {
                    name: "RecreateAbility", label: "Business Can Recreate", width: 120, align: "center", formatter: "checkbox",
                    stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" },
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "true:false", defaultValue: "false" }
                },
                { name: "ResendRecreateDetails", label: "Resend/Recreate Details", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "BusinessOwnerName", label: "Business Platform Owner", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "BusinessSponsorName", label: "Business Sponsor", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "BusinessSponsorEmailAddress", label: "Sponsor Email", width: 120, editable: true },
                {
                    name: "BusinessSponsorConfirmedDate", label: "Sponsor Confirmed", width: 120, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                    formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "Y-m-d" }, editable: true,
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch }
                },
                { name: "FailureContactEmailAddress", label: "Failure Email", width: 120, editable: true },
                {
                    name: "FailureContactConfirmedDate", label: "Failure Confirmed", width: 120, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                    formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "Y-m-d" }, editable: true,
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch }
                },
                { name: "SmeAnalystName", label: "SME/Analyst", width: 120, editable: true },
                { name: "SmeAnalystEmailAddress", label: "SME/Analyst Email", width: 120, editable: true },
                {
                    name: "SmeAnalystConfirmedDate", label: "SME/Analyst Confirmed", width: 120, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                    formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "Y-m-d" }, editable: true,
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch }
                }
                
            ],            
            loadonce: true,
            forceClientSorting: true,
            cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
            autoResizing: { compact: false, adjustGridWidth: false },
            shrinkToFit: false,
            autowidth: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            height: "auto",
            sortname: "Campaign",
            sortorder: "asc",
            threeStateSort: true,
            sortable: true,
            pager: true,
            rowNum: 10,
            viewrecords: true,
            searching: {
                defaultSearch: "cn"
            },
            multiSort: true,
            formEditing: {
                onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata, formOper) {
                    return {};
                }
            }
        }).jqGrid("setFrozenColumns")
            .jqGrid("navGrid", { add: true, edit: true, del: true })
            .jqGrid("inlineNav", { add: false, edit: false })
            .jqGrid("filterToolbar")
            .jqGrid("gridResize");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Json(gridData);

Instead of the above code please place the below code.

int totalRecords = gridData.Count();
var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
 var Data = new
                {
                    total = totalPages,
                    page,
                    records = totalRecords,
                    rows = gridData
                };
                return Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```